# How to center text inside div in this specific situation?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, centering

How to center the text inside that box?

Here's how I want elements sorted out:

[image]

In a smaller screen, elements stack on top of each other, and the `.text-box` div, that contains the text I want to center, has a fixed height. For larger widths, the `.text-box` div should have a height igual to larger image's height minus shorter image's height

[See the Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/isaacalves/6qdd1zcb/)

HTML

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="img-large" src="http://placekitten.com/900/800" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/900/400" alt=""/>    
    </div>
    <div class="box-text">
        <div class="vcenter-outer">
            <div class="vcenter-inner">
                <p>center this text vertically</p>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    background: #ffeaea;
    height: 100vh;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.img-large {
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box-text {
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .box {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
}

.vcenter-outer {
    background: yellow;
    display: table;
}

.vcenter-inner {
    background: lightblue;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Why does the `.text-box` div span through the whole wrapper?

Comment: [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: Have you tried making it not display as a table and instead as a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly You could use display:flex and float together

```css
.trio {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vh;
}
.trio>div {
  float:left;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:50vh;
  height:50vh;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px;
}
.trio .first {
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="trio">
  <div class="first">
    <p>Center</p>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    <p>Center</p>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    <p>Center</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

display:table works too with an extra level of div inbricated as you did , same idea: `float` + `vh`

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xbpdgZ)

Comment: Nice! I'm close to what I want to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/isaacalves/6qcu2pxy/  I just can't make the images bleed horizontally and keep centered inside their div